# Mongodb installation Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

My mongodb installation isn't working very well. I added a place in /etc/apt/sources.list, but I get an error message that there is a duplicate in an entry between the i386 packages and amd64 packages? I tried an update, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this [how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), each step was well explained. I tried and it went well as expected. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

Its easy to install mongodb in ubuntu.

**Step 1**: Search for the mongodb package avaliable but initially it may not be present

```
sudo apt-cache search mongodb
```

**Step 2**: Add the package to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` because its the the latest stable MongoDB version

```
vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

Add the following link into the mongodb.list file

```
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

**Step 3**: Import the GPG key

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
```

**Step 4** : Update the debian package using the command:

```
apt-get update
```

**Step 5**: Now perform search to view the package

```
apt-cache search mongodb
```

**Step 6**: Now the package will be present so install it using the below command:

```
apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

**Step 7**: Check mongodb has started using

```
ps -ef | grep mongo
ls -ls /usr/bin | grep mongo
```

**Step 8**: The mongodb control script is generated at /etc/init.d/mongodb,the MongoDB config file is at /etc/mongodb.conf add  the below details:

```
verbose = true
dbpath = /data/db
logpath = /var/log/mongodb.log
logappend = true
port = 27017
```

**Step 9**: Start the mongodb as a service

```
service mongodb start
```

**Step 10** :Check mongodb service has started using

```
ps -ef | grep mongodb
```

**Step 11** : To stop/restart perform the below commands:

```
service mongodb stop
service mongodb restart
```

This is taken from my [blog post](http://jerwinroy.blogspot.in/2015/02/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu.html), which I have explained in further detail.

Answer (score 0):

Download and Unzip the .tar .zip and invoke in terminal $.\mongod (after unzip, it runs server instance on default port), Use another terminal and try $.\mongo (show dbs, use dbname, show collections,...)

Depending on the 32bit/64bit version depending on your system capability use 32/64 bit.

Comment: why this way if packages are available through apt

Answer (score -1):

```
first you have to configure Ubuntu Package Management System (APT)
to be able to get the public GPG key

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10 
or type
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

another issue you may face it's when you want to connect
to the internet through proxy, export proxy settings to you bash configuration
- add this line with your proxy address (at the end of file /etc/bash.bashrc):

export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver:port/ 

now Create a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list file and include 
the following line in the 10gen.list for the 10gen repository:

deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen

if you get that went right you have to update the packages
sudo apt-get update

now install mongodb package:
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen

and you good !!!
```