# mongodb on ubuntu 14.04 default data/db path

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to install mongodb on Ubuntu 14.04.
I am new to linux. I figured out how to install ubuntu and become su to the root as well as how to set up environment path

I am just wondering where exactly the default path suppose to be for mongodb.
should I use root and put the data/db in the root directory?

When I install the mongo db it tell me to run the sudo mongo install (don't remember exactly what the command is) it runs and installs, A mongodb folder then appears in the system where etc folder is. also there is a folder in /var/lib/mongodb.

also I have to `chmod 777` for the data/db I don't think I was able to do this.

So where exactly data/db suppose to reside by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongodb installation Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462057/mongodb-installation-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at mongod.conf file.

Default working directory should be "/data/db" -  if is now exist - just create is. No need to chmod 777 if you create the directory and run mongo as root user.

If you want to start mongod with other working directory - modify mongod.conf file or start mongod with --dbpath /pathtootheremptyfolder/

Please let me know if you are OK.

Comment: hi thanks for your help Max- I got it working with su, but I tried all kinds I always had to use mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb for it to work. what I wanted to do is set the data/db folder in my home directory doesnt seem to work. I used mongod --dbpath /home/username/data/db.. fails. given I am in the mongodb folder I am going to setup my shard now.

Comment: Shards should be easy - but please pay attention which port do use to set up shards. you can find some good tutorials on youtube.